How do I configure the Thunar file manager
Xubuntu 22.04, how do I edit/modify the thunar file manager sendto menu?

You can create a relevant .desktop file under the folder ~/.local/share/Thunar/sendto/. For example, put the following content into a file named ~/.local/share/Thunar/sendto/gedit.desktop:
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.1
Type=Application
Name=GNOME Text Editor
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-text-editor %f

Then you will see the item named GNOME Text Editor in the Send To menu.
For the %f specifier in the Exec= line, see The Exec key variables in Desktop Entry Specification.
